# java.awt.HeadlessException thrown from HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice

Tags: java, awt, headless

I need to do some image processing on a java server (Debian with java version "1.6.0_12"),
and I am receiving java.awt.HeadlessException from my code:

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
    at sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:64)
    at WaxOn.getDefaultConfiguration(WaxOn.java:341)
```

Even when java.awt.headless is set to true (as evident by this code printing so):

```
if (!java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless())
{
    logger.warn("Headless mode is not enabled");
}
else
{
    logger.info("Headless mode");
}
```

This is the code that throws the exception:

```
public static GraphicsConfiguration getDefaultConfiguration()
{
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    return gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When headless you don't have a screen device. The [documentation is clear](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getDefaultScreenDevice%28%29):

> Throws:
>      HeadlessException - if isHeadless() returns true

Comment: When isHeadless is false, the jvm attempts to connect to the X server. headless mode supposed to support some operations without an X server.

Comment: This is also very clear: http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/reference/faqs/index.html , look for 'headless' in that document.

Comment: Okay. how do I perform a bicubic image resize without an (god this is stupid) x server in Java?

Comment: The documentation of the method says that it must throw exception if in headless mode. So there's nothing more to that - it just is not possible. If you feel this is wrong, you can create an issue in the oracle bug tracking system.

Comment: @Omry - that is another question - feel free to ask it as a new one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be getting the default graphics device configuration on a machine that doesn't have a usable graphic device.  This doesn't make much sense, and is never going to work.

If you could explain why you are trying to do this (on a headless machine) we might be able to offer an alternative.

Comment: I am trying to resize and crop an image. it makes perfect sense to be able to do this without an X server.

Comment: and btw: the mare fact that there is a class named HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment (see the stack trace) suggest that there is a good chance that this will actually work.