# HeadlessException using docx4j xhtmlrenderer on RedHat server

Tags: linux, redhat, headless, docx4j, xhtmlrenderer

I'm getting a `java.awt.HeadlessException` when using a `Docx4jReplacedElementFactory` on a RedHat server. Does anyone know of a workaround for this? (other than running Xvfb)

I've drilled in to the stack trace and the source of the problem is `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice()`, which throws the exception when running in a headless environment. *This is as documented:* "throws: HeadlessException - if isHeadless() returns true" (see comment on [java.awt.HeadlessException thrown from HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534400/java-awt-headlessexception-thrown-from-headlessgraphicsenvironment-getdefaultscr)).

Given `getDefaultScreenDevice` is working as specified, is there another approach when using docx4j that avoids going there?

Looking at the source of `org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.util.ImageUtil.getGraphicsConfiguration`, we see:

```
private static GraphicsConfiguration getGraphicsConfiguration() {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
  -> GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = gs.getDefaultConfiguration();
    return gc;
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Cause details:
java.awt.HeadlessException
    at sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.util.ImageUtil.getGraphicsConfiguration(ImageUtil.java:119)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.util.ImageUtil.makeCompatible(ImageUtil.java:70)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.AWTFSImage.createImage(AWTFSImage.java:38)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.NaiveUserAgent.createImageResource(NaiveUserAgent.java:197)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.NaiveUserAgent.getImageResource(NaiveUserAgent.java:167)
    at org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.docx.Docx4jReplacedElementFactory.createReplacedElement(Docx4jReplacedElementFactory.java:57)
[snip]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply [this recent upstream patch](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/commit/25a28383cb8fdedd727cd260362d0aff3af2c457#flying-saucer-core/src/main/java/org/xhtmlrenderer/util/ImageUtil.java)

Comment: Perfect. I was able to override that one class with a version that included the patch and it's now working. Based on the line `if (GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless())` it was looking good from the start. Many thanks.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the package structure in this solution. I think it needs to be modified to `org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.util` as this is the version of the class used

Comment: The fix is present in http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/xhtmlrenderer-nightly-20130903.jar

Comment: Hi Jason I cant find that copy of the xhtmlrenderer jar. Is it stored anywhere else?