# awt headless exception type SOAP fault when calling web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have a Java application which I will be using to send the values of some `jTextFields` via a web service to a database. When testing this feature, I get the following error on the client:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client
>   received SOAP Fault from server: java.awt.HeadlessException Please see
>   the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the
>   failure.
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:116)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:189)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:276)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.insertDVD(Unknown Source)     at
>   code.insertView.insertDVD(insertView.java:176)    at
>   code.insertView.jButton1ActionPerformed(insertView.java:169)  at
>   code.insertView.access$000(insertView.java:13)    at
>   code.insertView$1.actionPerformed(insertView.java:68)     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

And the following exception in GlassFish:

> Severe:   java.awt.HeadlessException  at
>   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
>     at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:536)  at
>   java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420)     at
>   java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:385)     at
>   javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.(SwingUtilities.java:1758)
>     at
>   javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1833)
>     at javax.swing.JOptionPane.getRootFrame(JOptionPane.java:1696)  at
>   javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:863)    at
>   javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:666)   at
>   javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:637)   at
>   javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:608)   at
>   webServicePackage.NewWebService.insertDVD(NewWebService.java:27)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.InstanceResolverImpl$1.invoke(InstanceResolverImpl.java:143)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)  at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:136)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:142)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)  at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:136)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:210)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:142)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)  at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:420)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:687)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:266)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:169)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I looked around on StackOverflow and Google's results and I couldn't find a `HeadlessException` thus being excepted.

Here is the code on the button click:

```
      private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String titleVal=titleField.getText();
        int yearVal=Integer.parseInt(yearField.getText());
        String actorsVal=actorField.getText();
        double ratingVal=Double.parseDouble(ratingField.getText());
        String formatVal=formatField.getText();
        int copiesVal=Integer.parseInt(copiesField.getText());

        insertDVD(titleVal, yearVal, actorsVal, ratingVal, formatVal, copiesVal);
    }
```

The code for the web service call method:

```
    private static String insertDVD(java.lang.String title, int year, java.lang.String actors, double rating, java.lang.String format, int copies) {
        webservicepackage.NewWebService_Service service = new webservicepackage.NewWebService_Service();
        webservicepackage.NewWebService port = service.getNewWebServicePort();
        return port.insertDVD(title, year, actors, rating, format, copies);
    }
```

And the web service's web method:

```
      @WebMethod(operationName = "insertDVD")
    public String insertDVD(@WebParam(name = "title") String title, @WebParam(name = "year") int year, @WebParam(name = "actors") String actors, @WebParam(name = "rating") double rating, @WebParam(name = "format") String format, @WebParam(name = "copies") int copies) {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (title+" "+Integer.toString(year)+" "+actors+" "+Double.toString(rating)+" "+format+" "+Integer.toString(copies)));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Values received");
    return null;
    }
```

EDIT: Even though the other question here:[java.awt.HeadlessException thrown from HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534400/java-awt-headlessexception-thrown-from-headlessgraphicsenvironment-getdefaultscr) also has a similar error, that error arises when trying to do some image processing. My error simply arises without any call whatsoever to any such library, class, or method. I'm not trying anything complex, it's a really simple thing, which throws an exception which it isn't supposed to!

Comment: Why the downvote? If you say why, couldn't I improve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.awt.HeadlessException thrown from HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534400/java-awt-headlessexception-thrown-from-headlessgraphicsenvironment-getdefaultscr)

Comment: @Joe but all I'm doing is calling a webmethod. Why should that even trigger a HeadlessGraphics call?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seemed that a message dialog can't be created from within a web service. I had no idea that this would happen, since it would perfectly in C#.

Sorry if the question seemed unnecessary.